# How to set $https value using HttpMapModule in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to add following block in `http` context to set `$https` based on `$http_x_forwarded_proto`:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $https {
    default off;
    https on;
}
```

But configuration test fails saying:

```
nginx: [emerg] the duplicate "https" variable in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Going to ask the obvious... did you declare the variable `https` already?

Comment: No. Where and how should I set it. I tried `set $https off;` but its not allowed here.

Comment: Post rest of your config. On a side note, I find the naming of a variable "https" quite poor choice, since there's one very close ($http) in nginx that's reserved.

Answer (score 4):

There is from a change in versin 1.1.11, where the variable $https became an internal variable.

Since it's now an internal, and the request itself isn't over HTTP, the best way is to pass along this info to the fastcgi handler. Here is what I have in my nginx.conf (via an include)

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
  default '';
  https on;
}
```

Then I have the below in the location block handling the `fastcgi_pass`

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $http_x_forwarded_port;
```